# why is the banner a bit off when moving the sites

Tags: php, html, css

I am currently moving an expression engine site from one domain to another but i am having problems with the homepage banner css/html

the original site is [here](http://www.airdyesolutions.com/)
the new site is [here](http://www.spa-med.net/)

and everything else looks fine except the banner....any ideas

Comment: `diff` shows several differences between the two pages. Are you sure that you've copied the proper version?

Comment: yes i am positive ..i notice that the new site has main_content and in firebug its invisible....why is that and could that be causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give #main-content a width like 850px like you did div below it. also change:

```
body.home #main_content {
    min-height: 0;
}
```

to

```
body.home #main_content {
    min-height: height-of-slide;
}
```

that should fix your problem